Nginx equivalent not working
Apache mod_rewrite (.htaccess):
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^posts/?$ post.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)?$ post.php?title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

Nginx:
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   c:/www;

    location / {
        index  index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:7000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ "^/([^/]+)/$" {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ "^/posts/?$" {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /post.php$is_args$args;
    }
    rewrite ^/posts/([^/]*)?$ /post.php?title=$1 last;
}
    

What is wrong with my Nginx equivalent?
I see this: when I try to navigate 127.0.0.1:3000/posts

404 Not Found
nginx/1.24.0


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community, I am trying to get beautiful urls under nginx just like on Apache.
